# How to get input from user in Eggplant?

Tags: android, automation, eggplant

I am currently automating my Eggplant script to run a USSD app on Android. For this I place the focus on the Textbox, and then typetext("12") and move on.

Is there a way I can get this typed input from the test user?

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I recently started working on eggPlant for Android and thought I'd reply.

At the point where you wish to enter user-defined choice, you can use the `ask` command and `it` variable:

```
ask "Please enter your choice:"
put it into choice
```

[More info](http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-user-interaction.htm)